# how to get check out version of source code used from a docker, k8s manifest files

Tags: git, docker, github, kubernetes

is there a way to get the details of source code like it check out version etc. on which the docker image is built? Using docker or Kubernetes manifest files or helm chart files? e.g. from a given manifest file, I need to know which tag/version of code used from open source GitHub repo of https://github.com/o-ran-sc/ric-plt-a1.git   is used in building its image.

```
  a1mediator:
  image:
    registry: "nexus3.o-ran-sc.org:10002/o-ran-sc"
    name: ric-plt-a1
    tag: 3.0.1
  rmr_timeout_config:
    a1_rcv_retry_times: 20
    ins_del_no_resp_ttl: 5
    ins_del_resp_ttl: 10
```

Comment: Only if your build pipeline somehow embeds the information in the built application

Comment: Although we don't tag the image, we create k8s labels on each pod with various metadata, like the branch and commit sha.

Comment: @David M. Karr  where and how to see such metadata in k8s?

Comment: It's part of the metadata of a pod.  Remember that, as the other comments and the answer pointed out, it won't be there unless you put it there. It's not magic.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the general case, no. Sometimes the image "leaks" source information such as the sha256 of the artifacts that are copied into the image, timestamps on the files, or other side-band data. But most of those are just heuristics or tricks, as there is no association with the source of the docker context